# Facebook Send request without opening FBWebDialog in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I want to send request to my all facebook friends without opening dialog(in background). How can i do it? I have used the following code but its not working.

```
if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        // if the session is closed, then we open it here, and establish a handler for state changes
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                           allowLoginUI:YES
                                      completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState state,
                                                             NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                    message:error.localizedDescription
                                                                   delegate:nil
                                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alertView show];
            } 
            else if (session.isOpen) {

                FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
                [friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                              NSDictionary* result,
                                                              NSError *error) {
                    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
                    NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);

                    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends)
                    {
                            NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend.name, friend.id);


                           NSString *urlAsString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/apprequests?message=hello&access_token=%@",friend.id,session.accessTokenData.accessToken];
                                urlAsString = [urlAsString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];
                                NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
                                [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                                                   queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                                                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
                                 {
                                     if (error==nil)
                                     {
                                         NSMutableData *webdata=[[NSMutableData alloc]initWithData:data];

                                         NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webdata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                                         NSLog(@"webdata myString == %@",myString);

                                     }
                                 }];

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                }];
            }
        }];
```

Any needful help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

//create sesion
//########## facebook   ******
    [self updateView];
    //   NSLog(@"appDelegate.session.isOpen %@",appDelegate.session.isOpen);
    if (!delegateObj.session.isOpen) {
        // create a fresh session object
        delegateObj.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
        // if we don't have a cached token, a call to open here would cause UX for login to
        // occur; we don't want that to happen unless the user clicks the login button, and so
        // we check here to make sure we have a token before calling open
        if (delegateObj.session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded)
        {
            // even though we had a cached token, we need to login to make the session usable
            [delegateObj.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState status,
                                                             NSError *error) {
                [self updateView];

            }];
        }
    }

}











-(void)Share_App:(id)sender{
    [self unload_popView];
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [controller setInitialText:@"https://itunes.apple.com/"];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
    }else{


//        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Please set your facebook account to post" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
//        [alert show];
        Stus=1;
        if (delegateObj.session.isOpen) {

            [self updateView];
        }else {
            //   NSLog(@"CLOSE  SESION    ");
            if (delegateObj.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {
                // Create a new, logged out session.
                delegateObj.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
            }

            [delegateObj.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                // and here we make sure to update our UX according to the new session state
                [self updateView];
            }];
        }


    }
}



//************************ load FB
- (void)updateView {

    if (delegateObj.session.isOpen) {
        NSLog(@"updateView  delegateObj.session.isOpen");
        // valid account UI is shown whenever the session is open
        //    NSLog(@"IF  %@",appDelegate.session.accessTokenData.accessToken);

        if (Stus==1) {
            [delegateObj featch_Data:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=%@",delegateObj.session.accessTokenData.accessToken]];
            NSLog(@"updateView Send data");

        }else if (Stus==2) {
            [self featch_Data:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=%@",delegateObj.session.accessTokenData.accessToken]];
        }

        Stus=0;


    } else {

        NSLog(@"updateView ELSE");


    }
}




-(void)featch_Data:(NSString *)urlString{

        Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
        NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
        NSDictionary* jsonFB ;
        if (internetStatus != NotReachable)
        {
            NSString *urlStr =urlString;
            NSLog(@"login url...%@",urlStr);
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];


            NSError *error;


            NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                            url];

            if (data==nil)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                jsonFB  = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data //1
                           options:kNilOptions   error:&error];
                //         NSLog(@"jsonFB  fb..%@",jsonFB);

              delegateObj.FbId =[jsonFB objectForKey:@"id"];
                [self  Share_appLink:delegateObj.FbId];
            }
        }
        else{

            UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"No network coverage" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            //alert.tag = 1;
            [alert show];
        }



    }


//*******************post on Wall

-(void)Share_appLink:(NSString *)UrserFBid{

        NSArray *permissions = @[@"publish_stream"];//publish_actions//publish_stream//create_note

        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState state,NSError *error)
         {


             NSArray *arr=[[total_record objectAtIndex:SmsTag] objectForKey:@"passenger"];
             NSString *SeatString=[[NSString alloc]init];
             for(int i=0;i<arr.count;i++)
             {
                 SeatString =  [SeatString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@\n",[[arr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"seat_number"],[[arr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"status"]]];
             }

             NSString *SmsString;



             NSMutableDictionary* parameters1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                 SeatString,@"message",
                                                 nil];

             FBRequest *request1= [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/feed",UrserFBid]
                                                       parameters:parameters1
                                                       HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                                   ];
             [request1 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                 if(error)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"result: %@, error: %@", result, error);
                 }else
                 {
                     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert!" message:@"App link share successfully" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                     [alert show];
                     // NSLog(@"Posted!");
                 }
             }];

         }];

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
-(IBAction)inviteFriends:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableString *text = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    // we pick up the users from the selection, and create a string that we use to update the text view
    // at the bottom of the display; note that self.selection is a property inherited from our base class



    NSString * friendId = [finalEmailArr componentsJoinedByString:@","];
 //   NSLog(@"%@",friendId);
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Hi please add me as a friend.",  @"message",
                                   friendId, @"to",
                                   nil];

    [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                                  message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi, your friend has invited you to join chaga.com"]
                                                    title:nil
                                               parameters:params
                                                  handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                                      if (error) {
                                                          // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
                                                       //   NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
                                                      } else {
                                                          if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                                                              // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                                                            //  NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                                                          } else {
                                                            //  NSLog(@"Request Sent.");
                                                              UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Successfully invited." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

                                                              [alert setDelegate:self];
                                                              [alert setTag:5];
                                                              [alert show];


                                                          }
                                                      }}];





    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"FVALCon"]==1) {

    }else{
         [self performSelector:@selector(remov_info) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];

    }

}
```